# How to integrate live555/WebRTC in laravel 5/5.2?

Tags: laravel, stream, webrtc, transcoding, laravel-5

i'm trying to test this tutorial - [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/800910/Broadcasting-of-a-Video-Stream-from-an-IP-camera-U), but the problem, i don't know how to integrate WebRTC lib into laravel 5.2 framework.

I'm trying to achieve:

1. Transcode RTSP live stream, to client browser/video player.
2. Broadcast live video stream, as many browser as possible.
3. Save Server resource, more than 1000 clients.

More explanations:

1. Steam live video protocol: RTSP codec H.256 -> Server like (WebRTC) transcode [SRTP,VP8]
   -> client browser.
2. Re-stream live video over server into client browser.

If there any other option to achieve this, please share it.

Comment: I think Webrtc capacity on live555 is not going to be out soon. But i am working on it right now. I would like to ask you where your investigations lead you ? And if you want we could help each other.